# What's the difference between %c and %C in printf?

Tags: c, printf, visual-c++

I can only find references for small c. I assume that the capital C is for Unicode, but I'm not sure. For lower numbers, both output the same character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN:

%c

```
type: int or wint_t
```

> When used with printf functions,
>   specifies a single-byte character;
>   when used with wprintf functions,
>   specifies a wide character.

%C

```
type: int or wint_t
```

> When used with printf
>   functions, specifies a wide character;
>   when used with wprintf functions,
>   specifies a single-byte character.

more about format specifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w(VS.71).aspx)

%c

When used with printf functions, specifies a single-byte character; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a wide character.

%C

When used with printf functions, specifies a wide character; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a single-byte character.

Answer (score 4):

Note that %C isn't standard.  Standard conversion for characters are:

- %c is used for a `int`.  `printf` output it as it if was an `unsigned char`.  `wprintf` output the result of the convertion to a `wchar_t` by `btowc`.
- %lc is used for a `wint_t`.  `printf` output the result of the conversion to a multibyte string by `wcrtomb`.  `wprintf` output it as if it was a `wchar_t`.

Comment: Which also implies that the Microsoft behaviour for %c in the *w*printf functinos is also non-compliant. From MSDN: "The types C, n, p, and S, and the behavior of c and s with printf functions, are Microsoft extensions and are not ANSI compatible."

Comment: The standard defines a behavior for n and p which seems to match the one described in the MSDN link above (which doesn't mention n and p as extension BTW).  And I assume that the use of printf instead of wprintf is a typo.  Looking at that page, I see another Microsoft extension: the use of h as modifier with c and s which gives them back their standard behavior.